# How do you go about making an underwater gooey sound?

Tags: creativity, ideas, inspiration

There is probably a way to blend the two sounds together like morph a goo sound into a crawling sound so it sounds like crawling underwater in goo.

Comment: It would help if you said what you have tried already?

Answer (score 4):

Hey

Wet one of those extra thick/absorbent cleaning cloths or a towel. Squish away. Itmight sound a bit wet though...

Make a mush with toilet paper and water. You can easily vary the wetness.

---

For underwater sounds, cover a make with a condom and record yourself squeezing water from a sports bottle/water pistol/super soaker...or like Dom Lawrence mentioned, playing with a sponge also gives great results...

Answer (score 3):

A bit vague on what exactly you want - is it big/small/human/animal etc etc but try cold pasta and sauce, squeezed and mushed up by hand for the goo.  SLowing it down, some short delay/rvb all help to thicken the sound.  As for underwater, try mic in a condom and squeeze out spunges underwater and then edit in the results to the picture movements.  Then blend with some eq/reverb/spatial plugs to help the underwater feel.

Have you tried vocoding one sound with the other??

Answer (score 0):

Those are great ideas, I especially love the pasta sauce.  No experimenting has been done except this question.

Comment: maybe you should read Randy Thoms article on the yahoo sound design group about experimenting before asking others advice? Seems sad when people don't even bother to experiment first & learn to develop their own instincts

Comment: I agree with Tim. There's nothing like going out and trying it before asking advice. Then you have something to relate the advice to.

Comment: Fair point Tim, asking about how to create creature/monster voices is a good example of this.  I kinda feel guilty for making suggestions now...!

Comment: Oh yes I completely agree with you but consider the sounds of everyone typing, thinking, and experimenting with those.  My question was poorly worded and was halfway asking about software reccomendations.